# Angular Export pdf with image and large dataset up to 10000

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, pdf-generation, html-pdf

I have created stackblitz link with 500 records just for testing and understanding. Once we click on save pdf and we scroll everything becoming white page. After export complete we can able to view data on scroll.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iykutg-2ncdfn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I am using kendo-pdf-export because need to render title page , header and footer and 2 types of grid single grid and drill down data grid. With current implimentation facing issues like ***Browser hang, Data getting trimmed at when page ends and Page alignment is not in control***

How I can export pdf in background with webworker using kendo-pdf-export or any other plugin where i can achive pdf export with multiple large datasets and customization with angular.
Any comments and suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks a Lot.